# Java Spring SessionFactory bean could not be found

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate to connect to a database and have autowired the SessionFactory bean into my DAO as follows:

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getCurrentSession(){
  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

However, the SessionFactoy bean could not be found. Instead I am told to do the following: `Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.`

I am Aware that I could do this with a XML file; however, I would prefer to work purely Annotation based as I am doing now. This also means that as of right now I am not working with a XML file.

Question: How do I define the Session Factory bean (ideally without a XML file)?

Comment: wasn't Aware of that. Would you mind elaborating and suggesting an alternative.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko a DAO and an entity class are completely different things. It's perfectly normal to use a Hibernate session in a DAO.

Comment: Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java.